# Using constructor with react and p5, getting 'Cannot read property 'stroke' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the title says it all, I can't get it working. Any help is appreciated. I am pretty new to react.
I am trying to 'bound' multiple bubbles in an array to make a collision system between them but can't get past this undefined error:

[image: Screenshot showing error message]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sketch from "react-p5";
import logo from'../assests/cyber.png';

var speed = 15;
var multiplier=0.3
var img;
var Bubbles = [];

class Card {
    constructor(p5) {
        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(window.innerWidth));
        this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(window.innerHeight));
        this.display = () => {
            p5.stroke(255);
            p5.noFill();
            p5.ellipse(this.x, this.y,50,50);
        };
        this.move = () => {
            this.x = this.x + Math.random() * Math.floor(1);
            this.y = this.y + Math.random() * Math.floor(1);
        }
    }
};

export default class Background extends Component {
    x = 50;
    y = 50;
    preload = p5 => {
        console.log('preload');
    }
    setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
        img=p5.loadImage('../assests/cyber.png');
        p5.createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight).parent(canvasParentRef); // use parent to render canvas in this ref (without that p5 render this canvas outside your component)
        for(var i = 0; i<5;i++)
            Bubbles[i] = new Card();
        };

        draw = p5 => {
            p5.clear()
            p5.image(img, this.x+100, this.y,150,150);
            p5.image(img, this.x+200, this.y,150,150);
            p5.image(img, this.x+300, this.y,150,150);
            p5.ellipse(this.x, this.y, 150,150);
            for(var i = 0; i<5;i++){
                  Bubbles[i].move();
                  Bubbles[i].display();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
            Bubbles[i] = new Card();
```

You are not passing your `p5` variable into the Card constructor. You can fix this error by changing the line to:

```
            Bubbles[i] = new Card(p5);
```

Comment: @Andrei-LucianRadu great to hear! Please flag the answer as correct when you have a moment :)